# Is there a way to display members a discord bot is serving

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was thinking of a possibility to check the total amount of members a discord bot is serving. I made a status that would show the number of servers the bot is in, but I also wanted to add the number of members the bot is serving.

Comment: `client.users.cache` would give you the collection of users, who have been using the bot. Loop inside the collection and then access users info. And `client.users.cache.size` would give you the amount of members using the bot.

Comment: What do you mean by "serving"? as @Radnerus said you can get all the users who have sent a message to a server the bot is in with `client.users.cache.size` but it isn't clear what you want exactly